# Labeled data: two concentric circles i.e. a cluster encircled by different clusters

Tags: data-request, geospatial, medical, machine-learning, finance

For my theoretical work, I have generated synthetic data where a single cluster is completely encircled by other clusters, in 2D the data set has the form (roughly) as in the picture below:

[image: data]

I am looking for some real data that have a similar characteristic, dimensionality is not of importance (for visualization I can use PCA and project to 3D).

I have looked through most of the data sets in [UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) and randomly searched on the internet but could not find what I am looking for...

Intuitively I would expect that many rich data sets should have this layout, that is one cluster of similar objects and all the rest of the data which is a noise in which the cluster is immersed.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me out which data usually has this layout (medical data, econometrics, imaging, geospatial data) any other suggestions would be very appreciated!